# Fulton algebraic curves: definition of intersection number

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

On page 54 of [Fulton's curve book](http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~wfulton/CurveBook.pdf) the intersection number of two projective plane curves is defined. If $P\in P^2_k$, and $F$ and $G$ are two projective plane curves, then $I(P,F\cap G)$ is defined as $dim_k (O_P(P^2_k)/(F_\star,G_\star))$. In my understanding, $O_P(P^2)$ is the set (actually a local ring) of fractions $H/K$ where $H$ and $K$ are homogeneous polynomials in $k[x,y,z]$, of the same degree, and $K(P)\neq 0$. I also know that $F_\star$ is $F(x,y,1)\in k[x,y]$. Now:

**Question 1:** *Why/in what sense can I consider $F_\star$ as element of $O_P(P^2)$? $F_\star$ is not necessarily a fraction of homogeneous polynomials of the same degree. Help me clarify the above definition.*

**Question 2:** *On page 57, in the proof of Bezout's theorem, why is true that $\sum_P I(P,F\cap G)=\sum_PI(P,F_\star\cap G_\star)$? Assuming $P=[a:b:1]\in P^2 $, in the left term of the above equation, is intendend $P=(a,b)\in A^2$ in the right term?* I have understood the definition of intersection number for affine plane curves, but not for projective plane curves.

Comment: I think it should probably be $\mathcal{O}_P(\mathbb{A}^2)$, not $\mathcal{O}_P(\mathbb{P}^2)$.  (I couldn't even find a place where Fulton defined $\mathcal{O}_P(\mathbb{P}^2)$...)  In any case, quantities like multiplicity and intersection number are local in nature, so you should be able to restrict your attention to an affine open set containing the point $P$, and then compute with respect to these affine coordinates.

Comment: @André3000 $\mathcal{O}_{P}\left(\mathbb{P}^{2}\right)$ is in fact defined. For any projective (irreducible) variety $V$, we define $\Gamma_h(V)$ as the domain $k[X_1,X_2,X_3]/(I(V))$ and $k_h(V):= Frac(\Gamma_h(V))$. Then $k(V):=\{\alpha/\beta\in k_h(V)\mid \alpha,\beta \mbox{ are homogeneous of same degree}\}$

Comment: @rr01 You're right, I now see he defines it in chapter 4, p. 46. But the definition you wrote is only for subvarieties of $\mathbb{P}^2$; in general it's $\Gamma_h(V) = k[X_1, \ldots, X_{n+1}]/I(V)$.

Comment: Minato, Fulton redefines $F_*$ on p. 53: given points $P_1, \ldots, P_n \in \mathbb{P}^2$, choose a line $L$ that doesn't pass through any of them. If $F$ defines a curve $C$ of degree $d$, then let $F_* = F/L^d$. This is an element of $k(C)$ as per rr01's comment above.

Answer (score 2):

In general, for affine variety $V$ and its projective completion $V^*$ and point $P\in \mathbb P^2$ such that $P\in U_3=\{[x:y:z]\in\mathbb P^2\mid z\neq 0\}$, if we write $P=[x:y:1]$ and define $P_3:=(x,y)\in\mathbb A^2$, we have the isomorphism:

$\mathcal O_P(V^*)\approx\mathcal O_{P_3}(V)$

by the association:

$\frac {H+I(V^*)}{G+I(V^*)}\mapsto \frac{H_*+I(V)}{G_*+I(V)}$

So we have isomorphism  $\mathcal O_P(\mathbb P^2)\approx\mathcal O_{P_3}(\mathbb A^2)$

Therefore we can consider projective curves $F$ and $G$ as elements in $\mathcal O_P(\mathbb P^2)$.

So to express the statement in precise terms, define $a:=deg(F), b:=deg(G)$. 
Then we have $I(P,F\cap G):=dim_k(\mathcal O_P(\mathbb P^2)/(F/(X_3)^a),G/(X_3)^b))$ which coincides with $dim_k(\mathcal O_P(\mathbb A^2)/(F_*,G_*))$ by the ring isomorphism aforementioned.

An immediate question hence arises: If we dehomogenize with respect to $U_1$ or $U_2$ does this yield a different result? No, for suppose $P$ is simultaneously in $U_3$ and $U_2$. We have the equality:

$(F/(X_3)^a),G/(X_3)^b)=(F/(X_2)^a),G/(X_2)^b)$

as ideals in $\mathcal O_P(\mathbb P^2)$.